# AngularJs Exception Handler going in infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, exception

I'm trying to create an AngularJs app with Server level logging for Exceptions.

My Code:

**exceptionHandler.js**

```
app.config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($injector,$log, ExceptionModel, exceptionService){

       return function(exception, cause){
            //$log.error.apply( $log, arguments );
            var exceptionModel = new ExceptionModel();
            exceptionModel.Exception = "Exception";
            exceptionModel.Cause = "Cause";
            exceptionModel.StackTrace = "StackTrace";

            exceptionService.LogException(exceptionModel).
                             catch(function(){ // do nothing});

        };

    });

});
```

**exceptionService.js**

```
app.service("exceptionService", function ($injector) {

    var _logException = function (exception) {
            var $httpResource = $injector.get("$resource");
            return $httpResource(url, {}).post(exception).$promise;
    }
    this.LogException = _logException
});
```

Whenever above exception logging API is not available(404 error), AngularJs exceptionHandling goes in an infinite loop. Is there something I'm missing?

Is there a way I can suppress errors in AngularJs i.e., at $exceptionHandler not to raise an exception if something goes wrong in sending the error to Server API or if the error is handled at any layer.

Comment: I realize this is super old but did you ever solve it?  I just had a similar issue and it ended up being caused by an $httpInterceptor that was swallowing the responseError

Comment: @UmmmActually There were more pressing issues then and couldn't get to work on fixing the issue. And then I moved out of the project.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not need to inject the $injector for your service, you should be able to simply inject $resource. I would also recommend using a factory for your exceptionService instead, but what you have will work.

If you are running into an infinite loop, the returned method must be throwing an error during execution, which in turn calls the exception handler, which throws an error, and so on.

If something goes wrong during the post, it will not result in a thrown error. The problem may be in the constructor of ExceptionModel.

I do notice the variable url in the exceptionService is not defined anywhere, which may be throwing the error, unless that portion of the code was omitted for clarity.

Also, the post method is not available from the $resource, it is from $http. From your example, it appears you should switch from $resource to $http, as you are not using this as a resource:

```
app.service("exceptionService", function ($http) {
  var _logException = function (exception) {
    return $http.post(url, exception);
  }

  this.LogException = _logException;
});
```